# If rock is melted and put in a centrifuge at high temperature, will the component chemicals separate?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, density, centrifugal-force

Consider if you were on the Moon and did these steps:

- heat some lunar soil to well above its melting temperature
- put it in a suitable container on a centrifuge and spin it enough 
  to overcome the viscosity of the fluid, so if there is anything in it that *could* settle out into layers, it will
- this is in vacuum, so there is no convection heat loss
- reflective insulation around the container also slows radiative heat loss
- at 2500 K most of the constituent chemicals are in their liquid phase, about 80% of the soil by volume. That's at 1 atm, I don't know how doing this in vacuum would affect that, or if then putting it in a centrifuge would have an effect.
- what remains solid is the calcium oxide and magnesium oxide, each about 10% of the mix, usually
- at 1700 K, [Bowen's reaction series](http://jersey.uoregon.edu/~mstrick/AskGeoMan/geoQuerry32.html) begins - the metal oxides begin to crystallize.

What I don't know is if a melt like that will behave like a solution, and no matter the acceleration nothing is going to settle, or it is a suspension, where some of it will. All the questions of whether it is a good idea or it would be feasible to make the device can be left aside.

Here is a chart I made of the typical composition of soil on the surface of the lunar maria:

[image: molecular mass, melting point, proportion of metal oxides in lunar soil]

Comment: It may work but it sounds like an expensive process. Also, I don't think that the metal oxides that are listed above are particularly valuable so I'm not sure that this method could be economically justified. Oh, and then there's also the high cost of transporting the metal oxides back to Earth.

Comment: @Countto10 there are no chemical reactions involved, so i'm not sure it fits on Chemistry.

Comment: @SamuelWeir this is for in situ use. It's part of a look at long-term colonization options. Pure aluminum oxide and silica are valuable for glass, quartz, and refractory materials. Magnesia is also a good refractory material and a glass flux.

Comment: Most traditional processing methods don't work on the Moon because of the absence of the chemicals used here on Earth. It is a big challenge that is largely unsolved, so it is probable all solutions are going to be expensive.

Comment: It's definitely a chemical engineering problem, which unfortunately means it's not quite chemistry and its not quite physics!

Comment: You may have a problem with sublimation in a vacuum at high temperatures.  If so, you could use sublimation at specific temperatures to selectively strip out various chemical species as you increased the temperature of the mix (a centrifuge may not be required).  If you still want to use a centrifuge, how do you heat rapidly spinning samples without destroying the centrifuge?  Centrifuge metals are highly stressed, and high temperatures will affect the maximum stress that the device can tolerate.

Comment: @DavidWhite - that was certainly the plan for the chemicals that boil at a low temperature and are a small portion of the soil. At higher temperatures, can one expect the vapor to be mostly one thing? It maybe is a good solution, but also i wonder about the energy involved. At first i thought it might not be necessary to use a centrifuge at all, then i thought the gravity on the Moon could be too low to get layers forming. The centrifuge may not need to support the kind of accelerations they are usually used for, just a couple of gravities.

Comment: I'm not an expert in this area, but you can be sure that sublimation temperatures are not dependent on the local value of gravity.  For centrifuge design details, perhaps a centrifuge expert can provide some input to this forum.

Comment: Yeah, in that regard i was referring to layer formation, not anything about sublimation. The substance has some viscosity. You put it in the container and leave it - if you heat it there will be convection currents and no layers would ever form, it has to be heated before it goes in. So before the liquid cools to the point where it starts to crystallize, it has to separate into layers that can be drawn off. In such low gravity, maybe that wouldn't happen before it gets too cold.

Comment: Even if there are no chemical reactions (which is a big "if") some of the components of the molten mixture will dissolve in each other. Solutions cannot be separated by centrifuging - you need a heterogeneous mixture where the different particles have different densities, not a solution which is uniform at the scale of individual molecules.

Comment: @alephzero - That's very helpful. But does it apply to all the components? When some are melted and others are solid?

Comment: Vote to Close : Your question comes down to "Will this work?" That is an **engineering** question, requiring the consideration of many practical factors, and some expertise with relevant technology. You are not **asking about a specific physics concept** - such as "How does a centrifuge work?" or "What is the physical explanation for this phenomenon?"

Comment: @sammygerbil I actually asked for migration this morning, to Chemistry or Earth Sciences. But i disagree. I am not asking how such a thing would be made, just whether the physics says the result would be that the magma separates into layers. Its just that the physical situation is so different than it is on Earth, i have to describe a setup in order to make clear what the forces on the system really are.

Comment: I edited to clarify that.

Comment: As you point out : *What I don't know is if a melt like that will behave like a solution, and no matter the acceleration nothing is going to settle, or it is a suspension, where some of it will.* How a real material will behave - particularly a complex mixture of molten oxides, dissolved gases and suspended solids - is not a question which physics can easily answer. Physics can only tell you how ideal objects would behave. It may be a question which only experimental metallurgical knowledge can answer. Unfortunately there seems to be no Stack Exchange site with such expertise.

Comment: Since there's not an obviously better SE site for this question, I'm inclined to leave it here and see how it fares. If you decide after a while to cross-post somewhere else like [chemistry.se] or [earthscience.se], it's good ettiquette to be explicit about linking the questions together and explaining why you think the new question on another site is likely to be better. Interesting question; good luck!

Comment: Isn't this what differential centrifugation is supposed to do?